# ROS message sent but not received

Tags: python, callback, message, ros

I'm using ROS in my project and I need to send one message from time to time. I have this function:

```
void RosNetwork::sendMessage(string msg, string channel) {
    _mtx.lock();
    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = _n.advertise<std_msgs::String>(channel.c_str(),10);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    std_msgs::String msgToSend;
    msgToSend.data = msg.c_str();
    chatter_pub.publish(msgToSend);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    cout << "Message Sent" << endl;
    _mtx.unlock();
}
```

And I have this in python:

```
def callbackFirst(data):
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)
    print("Received message from first filter")

def callbackSecond(data):
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)
    print("Received message from second filter")

def listener():
    rospy.Subscriber("FirstTaskFilter", String, callbackFirst)
    print("subscribed to FirstTaskFilter")
    rospy.Subscriber("SecondTaskFilter", String, callbackSecond)
    print("subscribed to SecondTaskFilter")
    rospy.spin()
```

The listener is a thread in python.
I get to the function `sendMessage` (I see in the terminal "Message Sent" a lot of times) but I don't see that the python script receives the message.

Update: I tested the python callback with `rostopic pub /FirstTaskFilter std_msgs/String "test"` and this works perfectly.

Any thought?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are re-advertising the publisher every time and then you are immediately using it to publish something.
This is problematic as it needs some time for the subscribers to subscribe to newly emerging publishers. If you are publishing messages before the subscriber has finished with this, these messages will not arrive.

To avoid this problem, do not advertise a new publisher every time, but do it only once in the constructor of your class and store the publisher in a member variable. Your code could look something like this:

```cpp
RosNetwork() {
    _chatter_pub = _n.advertise<std_msgs::String>(channel.c_str(),10);
    ros::Duration(1).sleep(); // optional, to make sure no message gets lost
}

void RosNetwork::sendMessage(string msg, string channel) {
    ...
    _chatter_pub.publish(msgToSend);
    ...
}
```

The one-second-sleep after `advertise` makes sure that all existing subscribers can subscribe before you start publishing messages. This is only necessary, if it is important that not a single message gets lost. In most practical cases it can be omitted.

Comment: That was all. Thanks!

Comment: Please also consider @KingKong's comment that is more robust than waiting a certain time. Waiting for the number of subscribers to be different from 0 (while using `ros::Rate::sleep()` in-between) was the solution for me in a rostest situation.

Comment: @RolandSarrazin Checking the number of subscribers only works if the publishing node knows how many subscribers are expected, which is not generally the case.  In applications where a topic is not always subscribed to, waiting for subscribers could dead-lock the node.  Or if there are multiple different subscribers, only checking for the number to be > 0, could still miss some of them.

Comment: @luator I'm totally with you. In my context, a rostest environment, this was the most helpful solution, though, since I know the expected number of subscribers (the tested node).

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution to your problem is to use pub.getNumSubscribers() and wait until that is > 0. Then publish.