# Confirming an Image is Published to ROS

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I've been trying to get an image to post to ROS (using Python/rospy), and while I think I have the method right, I'm having a hard time confirming it. Using

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=(topic)
```

doesn't seem to show anything. I've also tried rqtbag, but I don't really know how that thing works, other than it doesn't show things published, anyways.

A few notes before pasting my current code:

1. The code I use right now is based off of code I have gotten to work previously. I've used a similar setup to post text images to ROS, and those output fairly reliably.
2. This is slightly modified here. Most of this code is part of an `on_message` function, since this all runs through MQTT when implemented. (The logic is acquire image on one system -> encode it -> transfer to other system -> decode -> publish to ROS.)
3. I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu, and ROS Indigo.

Without further ado, my current code for publishing:

```
rospy.init_node('BringInAnImage', log_level = rospy.INFO)

def convert(messagepayload):
    t = open('newpic.bmp','w')
    t.write(messagepayload)
    t.close()

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    img = base64.b64decode(msg.payload)

    convert(img)
    time.sleep(5) 
    source = cv2.imread('newpic.bmp')  #this should be a mat file

    # talk to ROS
    bridge = CvBridge()
    pub2 = rospy.Publisher('/BringInAnImage', Image, queue_size = 10)
    pub2.publish(bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(source, "bgr8"))
    print "uh..... done??"
```

I'm using a basic listening function to try and see what is going on (this is within a different script I execute in a separate terminal):

```
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/BringInAnImage", Image, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

The callback just prints out that the image was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to check if something is published on topic xyz

To check if a message is really published, you can use the `rostopic` command.
Run the following in a terminal to print everything that is published on the specified topic.  This is the easiest way to check if there is something published.

```
rostopic echo <topic_name>
```

See the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic) for more useful things `rostopic` can do.

## Why is the image not received by image_view?

While you are doing it basically right, your images will not be received by any subscriber for a not so obvious but fatal problem in your code: You are using the publisher (`pub2`) immediately after initializing it. Subscribers need some time to register to the new publisher and will not be ready before you publish the image (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812134/ros-message-sent-but-not-received/31813144#31813144)).

**➔ Do not initialize a publisher just before you need it but do it right in the beginning, when initializing the node.**